# regular expression, match any number after string

Tags: javascript, regex

My string looks like this:

```
\r\n\r\n\t\"unittime\":\"2017010100\", \r\n\t\"count"\r
```

Using a regex I want to match on any number that follows the word 'unittime' and before the '",' at the end, how do I do that?

So for the above string I would end up with

result = 2017010100

Comment: Please format your post in a way that makes it easier to read. Clear and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
unittime[^,]*?(\d+)
```

```js
var s = '\r\n\r\n\t\"unittime\":\"2017010100\", \r\n\t\"count"\r ';
var num = +(s.match(/unittime[^,]*?(\d+)/) || [])[1];

console.log(num);
```

#### Explanation

- `[^,]` matches any character that is not a comma
- `*?` repeats the previous pattern as few times as possible (= lazy, not greedy) in order to match the complete regular expression
- `(  )`: creates a capture group, which can later be referenced
- `\d`: matches a digit
- `+`: matches the previous pattern one or more times (greedy)

`s.match` returns an array with first the complete match (`unittime\":\"2017010100`), and in the next elements the values for the capture groups: we only have one such group, so at index 1 we'll get `2017010100`.

If there is no match, then `.match()` will return `null`. In that case the `||` will kick in and create an empty array instead. Either way, the result is an array. With `[1]` the capture group match is taken. Of course, `[]` does not have such an element, so in that case you get `undefined`.

Finally, this result (a string or `undefined`) is converted to a number with the unitary `+`.

Comment: Could you explain this to me a little, otherwise it is perfect.

Comment: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a use of capture groups?

```
/(unittime)(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(,)
```

The third capturing group `(\d+)` is your number.

First group matches 'unittime'.
Second matches any number of non digits.
Third is your number.
Fourth is some more non digits.
Fifth is the ending coma.

Comment: I don't think that regex is going to work as expected. I tried it here: https://regex101.com/r/O67WFZ/1

Comment: You're right. It'll match the whole thing from unittime to ','. The only thing here you can do is to later extract just the 3rd capturing group.